# Can the input layer of keras take customized input?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

In the documentation, the parameters of `model.fit()` are

`fit(self, x, y, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=10, verbose=1, callbacks=None, validation_split=0.0, validation_data=None, shuffle=True, class_weight=None, sample_weight=None, initial_epoch=0)`

My question is, can I have three different tensors as input therefore I can have something like `fit(x,y,z)`?

PS:

Sorry for the ambiguity. I believe the `fit(x_val, y_val)` function in keras acts similarly as `feed_dict={x:x_val, y:y_val}`, I am just wondering can I feed in more values I created in the model?

Comment: Could you explain us on which among x, y and z are part of input and which are part of output?

Answer (score 0):

This X is a tensor
For example

`X = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
y = [3,5,7]`

(The fitting line should be `y=X[0]+X[1]`)

So if you clear which are features (for example, the x and y in your requirement) and which is the target class (z), you can define:
`_X = (x,y) # two nodes in the input layer`
`_y = z`
`fit(_X,_y)`
Do you mean it?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I believe the `fit(x_val, y_val)` function in keras acts similarly as `feed_dict={x:x_val, y:y_val}`, I am just wondering can I feed in more values I created in the model?

Comment: @xxx222 x_val and y_val are features and target class of examples. Their relationship is what the machine learns. But I wonder the position of the "more values" you describe. You'd better tell more detail or example of your question/idea.